# Installing HEBMORPH plugin to elastic search

Tags: maven, plugins, elasticsearch

Im trying to install this "https://github.com/synhershko/HebMorph" plugin for elastic search. Theres the Instelation guide:
"http://code972.com/blog/2013/08/129-hebrew-search-with-elasticsearch-and-hebmorph"

But its all very blurry for me.

the first step stays

"Once you have the sources, run mvn package or mvn install to create 2 jars - hebmorph-core and hebmorph-lucene. Those 2 packages are required before moving on to the next step."

I run mvn install to the whole downloaded folder, and I end up in the java/target with 4 jar files
"hebmorph-lucene.jar"

"hebmorph-lucene-2.3.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"

"hebmorph-lucene-2.3.1-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar"

"hebmorph-lucene-2.3.1-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar"

I dont get the "hebmorph-core" file. 
And when I try to drag all those 4 files into the es/plugin folder, it does not work.

Did I do something wrong? or maybe the guide is just not up to date?

Comment: Hey, did you managed to solve this issue? I'm having the same thing...

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But I found this:
plugin –install analysis-hebrew --url https://bintray.com/artifact/download/synhershko/elasticsearch-analysis-hebrew/elasticsearch-analysis-hebrew-1.7.zip

already uploaded plugin. but the version of es required is 1.7 - 1.7.3.
1.7.3 was good enough for my needs so im working with it right now